# Can I add a newline and an HTML link in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextview

Messing about with interface builder for the first time, exploring my options. Text seems to be in one long batch--found another thread where someone was importing an SQL db, but I just want to type something with a CR. Or should I just make a new TextView item for that?

I've also found threads complaining about autodetected links, but I'm not getting those—links are simply treated as plain text. Not that surprising, but is there a way to turn autodetect on somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Interface Builder, there is an "Detection" panel where you can check a checkbox to detect links.  But it isn't detecting HTML, just text that is in the form of a URL.  As for carriage returns, though, a UITextView should be able to handle those just fine.

If you want to deal with HTML, though, you should look at a UIWebView.